# Creating a vector in class A with type of Class B - Issue accessing data [C++] [members are private in both classes]

Tags: c++

I keep getting errors because Class A are private members. I want to avoid making them public. I thought making the Class B friend of A would fix this.
I have created 2 class in 2 different header files as follows:

A.h

```
class A {
    friend class B;
private:
    std::string id;
    std::string name;
    std::string label;
public:
    A();
    ~A() {};
};
```

B.h

```
#include "A.h"

class B {
    friend class A;
private:
    std::string num;
    std::string data;
    std::vector<A> vec;
public:
    B();
    friend int display(B&);
    ~B() {};
};
```

B.cpp

```
int display(B& b){
// TESTING
    b.vec.resize(5);
    b.vec[0].id = "test";
    cout << b.vec[0].id << endl;
return 1;

}
```

error:

```
error: 'std::__cxx11::string A::id' is private within this context
```

Comment: What errors do you receive?

Comment: error: 'std::__cxx11::string A::id' is private within this context

Comment: Maybe you can't pass friends in c++. Have you tried to create a private method in B which receive an `A` and return its `id` field?

Comment: I need to be able to write and read from  A members with the vector created in class B. Because I am reading a file and putting the data in a A obj.

Comment: An option is to make `display` a class function of `B`, not a friend function

Comment: Okay, I made display a class function of B. Now my next problem is that it is returning this: A._M_dataplus._M_p->*_M_p = -var-create: unable to create variable object

Answer (score 0):

- Using friends in C++ is usually (99% of the cases) an indicator that something is wrong with the design. Since if A wants to know the private data of B, and B wants access to the private data of A... that usually means that A and B want to get merried (i.e. be the **same class**) !

  - A usual solution in your case (with the few details supplied) is to make A a [nested class](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/nested-classes-in-cplusplus) of B.
  - Or perhaps you should consider which class is the 'face' of your structure: if you have in mind that your class' users should use only B, then A might be hidden as a [PIMPL](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pimpl), (and then you'll expose an `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<A>>` as member of B, where A is an interface)
  - Think about it: you want A to have some members accessible only to B but to no one else... it doesn't work like that in OOP : if the class decides that something is public it should be public for all. Therefore - find ways to hide all of A begind B :)

Comment: How do you even deal with private members without using friends ? Is making friends function a bad design ? That is the only way I found to be able to read and write members

Comment: Note I find doing friend classes/functions is fine, really. It is more elegant than many other approaches (aka ad hoc interfaces). Making the classes friends is fine so long as they are closely related otherwise making all members public might be a better approach.

Comment: @CryptoDood: private members are private for one of two reasons: control who can change them *or* hide implementation details. In the first case: you expose them with Getter functions. A_Data const & GetAData() const; in the second scenario - you don't have any reason to expose them. 
"How to deal" - each scenario and the appropriate approach. I wrote what I think about your specific case. "Is it bad design" - usually it is an indicator of bad separation of responsibilities.

Answer (score 0):

## Problem

`display` is not a `friend` of `A`, so `display` cannot interact with `id`, a `private` member of `A`.

`A` is a `friend` of `B`. `A` can interact with the internals of `B`

`B` is a `friend` of `A`. `B` can interact with the internals of `A`

`int display(B&)` is not a member of `B`, but it is a `friend` of `B`. It can interact with the internals of `B`

`int display(B&)` is not a member of `A` or a `friend` of `A`. It can NOT interact with the internals of `A`. It does not inherit `B`'s `friend`ship with `A` through its `friend`ship with `B`. Only `A` gets to decide who its `friend`s are.

## Solution

Decouple `A` and `B` by adding a `display` function to `A` and calling it from `B`'s `display` function.

## TL;DR Explanation

Easy fix is to make `display` a `friend` of `A`. Easy, but now you're punching more holes in the encapsulation of your classes. This is a bad solution.

It is [generally preferable to use free functions](http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Rc-member), but the more the `friend` needs to know about the class's inner workings the more coupled they are and the less useful the recommendation becomes. `display` not only needs to know `B` has a `vec`, it must also know that the `A`s in `vec` contain an `id`. To me that's pushing it too far. If anyone changes `A` or `B`, `display` likely needs to be changed. But what if you add

```
friend int display(A&);
```

to `A` and call this `display` overload from the `B` `display` overload? Now `B`'s `display` only needs to know there is a `display` function for `A`s and knows absolutely nothing about what the other `display` function does or what's in `A`.

`display` just knows it needs to call `display` for all the `A`s in `vec`. It is a simple `for` loop.

Here what the code could look like:

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

class A {
    // no need to be a friend of B
    // const A& because a display function should not modify the displayed
    friend void display(const A&);
private:
    std::string id;
    std::string name;
    std::string label;
public:
    A(); // if this constructor doesn't do anything, remove it.
         // code that doesn't exist has no bugs.
    // destructor removed. See Rule of Zero
};

class B {
    // no longer any need to be a friend of A
private:
    std::string num;
    std::string data;
    std::vector<A> vec;
public:
    B(); // if this constructor doesn't do anything, remove it.
    friend int display(const B&);
    // destructor removed. See Rule of Zero
};

void display(const A& a){
// TESTING
    std::cout << a.id << std::endl;
}
int display(const B& b){
// TESTING
    for (const A & elem: b.vec) display(b.vec[0]);
    return 1; // does 1 really make sense here?
}
```

Note the absence of `friend`ship except for the `display` functions.

[The Rules of Three, Five, and Zero](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three). Only Zero is relevant to this question, but familiarize yourself with the other rules. You cannot write complicated, efficient C++ code without knowing when and how to apply all three rules.

In general keep all of your functions as ignorant as possible and use helper functions to perform tasks they don't need to know the details of.